# Using cftransaction does not rolling back the entry

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using the cftransaction tag and when error is coming, it is not rolling back the entry, i am not sure what is wrong, I am not using the nested part of cftransaction yet, simple one is not working, i am not sure how nested will behave here, correct my code if it is wrong guys...

```
<cffunction access="public" name="newRegistration" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="structform" default="" required="no" type="struct">
      <cfset var newregis = "">
      <cfset var str = "">
      <cfset var msg = "">
      <cftry>
        <cftransaction action="begin"/>
           <cfquery name="newregis" result="lastGenerated">
               --- Insert Goes Here ---
           </cfquery>
           <cfset rsLastID = lastGenerated.generated_key>
           <cfif isDefined('arguments.structform.mailoption') AND arguments.structform.mailoption EQ 'Yes'>
               <cfset msg = createAccountEmail(rsLastID,'nar')>
           </cfif>
           <cftransaction action="commit"/>
           <cfset str = "Account Created Successfully. #msg#">
           <cfcatch type="any">
             <cftransaction action="rollback"/>
             <cfset str = "Error! #cfcatch.Detail# #cfcatch.Message#. Entry rolled back, try again">
           </cfcatch>
         </cftry>
         <cfreturn str>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: read this `<cfset rsLastID = lastGenerated.generated_key()>` as `<cfset rsLastID = lastGenerated.generated_key>`

Comment: What is the error that is triggering the cfcatch block?  Also, regarding your comment, why don't you edit your question if it has a mistake?

Comment: oops! My Mistake, I did not edited, i had edited now. I make it fail though someway after the insert but it is not rolling back

Comment: Where is your closing `</cftransaction>`?

Comment: <cftransaction action="commit"/> like this,

Comment: No, that is not the closing `</cftransaction>`. As @AlE points out, you are not structuring the transaction tags correctly, which is [why it does not rollback](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:32309#162142).

Comment: so where would be the closing

Comment: Read the link I posted. It shows exactly how to structure the tags.

Comment: @AlE. - Looks like wrong tags is indeed the problem. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be missing the closing CFTRANSACTION tag which should be wrapped around the try/catch block.

```
<cftransaction action="begin">
    <cftry>
        ...
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cftransaction action="rollback" />
            ...
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cftransaction>
```

Use that structure and you should be good.

Comment: I do not think it can be nested inside the `cftry`, probably needs to be [more like this](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:32309#162146) (minus the closing `/` in `<cftransaction action="begin" />`). But you are right that incorrect tag structure is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, Here is found one entry which is almost same as mine as only thing is the main cftransaction action="begin" is outside the cftry bloack and closing is after th cftry. http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/using-cftry-to-log-a-failed-cftransaction/

Comment: Lol, that is exactly the same structure mentioned in the earlier link! You just had to plug in your code...